# How to convert a byte array back into a string?

Tags: python, arrays, compression

I have written a code for Huffman Compression. My padded encoded string is converted into a byte array using the following code:

```
def make_byte_array(self, padded_text):
    byte_array = bytearray()
    for i in range(0, len(padded_text), 8):
        byte_array.append(int(padded_text[i:i + 8], 2))

    return byte_array
```

How can I convert the byte array back into the original string of my padded encoded text?

**Edit:**

Here is some more context that might make answering the question a bit easier. The padded compressed text I am converting into a byte array is saved into a binary file. When I read the binary file this is the output I get:

```
b'\xd8\xd2.\xfdc\xa9\xfd\xc4\xa2R\xf8\xack\xb4\xfe\x07&@'
```

The above string is what I need to convert back into the compressed padded text.

To explain my code further, I have only created the Compression part, and I used Huffman Compression. Below is the code for my Huffman Compression:

```
class HuffmanCoding:
    def __init__(self, text_to_compress):
        self.text_to_compress = text_to_compress  # text that will be compressed
        self.heap = []
        self.codes = {}  # will store the Huffman code of each character
        self.decompress_map = {}

    def get_frequency(self):  # method to find frequency of each character in text - RLE
        frequency_Dictionary = {}  # creates an empty dictionary where frequency of each character will be stored

        for character in self.text_to_compress:  # Iterates through the text to be compressed
            if character in frequency_Dictionary:
                frequency_Dictionary[character] = frequency_Dictionary[character] + 1  # if character already exists in
                # dictionary, its value is increased by 1
            else:
                frequency_Dictionary[character] = 1  # if character is not present in list, its value is set to 1

        return frequency_Dictionary

    def make_queue(self, frequency):  # creates the priority queue of each character and its associated frequency
        for key in frequency:
            node = HeapNode(key, frequency[key])  # create node (character) and store its frequency alongside it
            heapq.heappush(self.heap, node)  # Push the node into the heap

    def merge_nodes(
            self):  # creates HuffmanTree by getting the two minimum nodes and merging them together, until theres
        # only one node left
        while len(self.heap) > 1:
            node1 = heapq.heappop(self.heap)  # pop node from top of heap
            node2 = heapq.heappop(self.heap)  # pop next node which is now at the top of heap

            merged = HeapNode(None, node1.freq + node2.freq)  # merge the two nodes we popped out from heap
            merged.left = node1
            merged.right = node2

            heapq.heappush(self.heap, merged)  # push merged node back into the heap

    def make_codes(self, root, current_code):  # Creates Huffman code for each character
        check = 0

        if root == None:
            return

        if root.char != None:
            self.codes[root.char] = current_code
            self.decompress_map[current_code] = root.char

        self.make_codes(root.left, current_code + "0")  # Every time you traverse left, add a 0 - Recursive Call
        self.make_codes(root.right, current_code + "1")  # Every time you traverse right, add a 1 - Recursive Call
        if len(self.decompress_map) == len(self.get_frequency()) and check == 0:  #####################################################
            codeDict = open("Codes.txt", mode="w")
            codeDict.write(str(self.decompress_map))
            codeDict.close()
            check = 1



    def assignCodes(self):  # Assigns codes to each character
        root = heapq.heappop(self.heap)  # extracts root node from heap
        current_code = ""
        self.make_codes(root, current_code)

    def get_compressed_text(self, text):  # Replaces characters in original text with codes
        compressed_text = ""
        for character in text:
            compressed_text += self.codes[character]
        return compressed_text

    def pad_encoded_text(self, compressed_text):
        extra_padding = 8 - len(compressed_text) % 8  # works out how much extra padding is required
        for i in range(extra_padding):
            compressed_text += "0"  # adds the amount of 0's that are required

        return compressed_text

    def make_byte_array(self, padded_text):

        byte_array = bytearray()
        for i in range(0, len(padded_text), 8):
            byte_array.append(int(padded_text[i:i + 8], 2))

        return byte_array

    def show_compressed_text(self):

        frequency = self.get_frequency()
        self.make_queue(frequency)
        self.merge_nodes()
        self.assignCodes()

        encoded_text = self.get_compressed_text(self.text_to_compress)
        padded_encoded_text = self.pad_encoded_text(encoded_text)

        byte_array = self.make_byte_array(padded_encoded_text)
        return bytes(byte_array)
```

The class HuffmanCoding takes in the text to be compressed. The show_compressed_text then spits out the byte_array of my compressed text. I then get this byte array, and write it to a binary file. I want to open this binary file, convert the byte array inside back into the string of 0's and 1's which represents my compressed text so that I can work on decompressing it. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: There is no single way of converting a byte into a string.  The answer below by @ninetendo works when the conversion was done using utf-8, the most common method.  The fact that it doesn't work means that *you* have to find out how the data was encoded, and then use the corresponding decoding technique.  That string above looks like gibberish to me.  Are you sure it isn't just binary?

Comment: What is "padded text" and how is it different from a regular Python string?

Comment: It should be a string of 0s and 1s. Into the make_byte_array function I pass a string of 0s and 1s (Thats what padded text is), and I believe the function allows me to convert them into binary so that they take up less space. I just want to go from the byte array back to the string of 0s and 1s (the padded text).

Comment: You mean it's literally a string like `"01001000"`? I think you need to provide a [mre] showing the input and expected output.

Comment: Huffman encoding converts byte strings to byte strings.  You seem to believe that someone, somewhere had a string, and converted that into a byte string, which was then Huffman encoded, and you decoded.  (1) What process was used for that conversion.  (2) Are you 100% sure that your decoder is working correctly.  As I sad above, that looks like gibberish, not text.

Comment: I have created the code to get any string and compress it using Huffman encoding. This compressed string is passed into the make_byte_array function so that I can convert the encoded string into actual bytes which are smaller in size. I want to get this byte array and convert it back into the compressed string. What is above isn't supposed to be the decompressed text: its supposed to be the Huffman encoded compressed version of the text.

Comment: Okay.  This makes more sense. Why do you need it to be a string?  The way to convert it to a string depends on what you're planning on doing with it.  You really, really just want it to remain bytes.

Comment: Basically I need it back into a string because I am now writing my decompression function. In a completely seperate python file I am making the decompression function - I need to be able to open the binary file with the compressed bytes inside and convert the bytes back into a string so that I can work with it and decompress it.